# getting node.js working

Tags: node.js

So I'm following:

http://giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=894

and installing node.js.

I got up to the part with sudo make install.

It works, then it says to create a js file.

What I don't understand is where I put the sayhello.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js looks at least for the programmer more like a interpreter. Thus, you can place your sayhello.js whereever you want and run it by executing `node sayhello.js`.

However, you might consider using external modules. Then you must check that they are set by full path or the relative path can be resolved from the location you execute node in.

Comment: You're welcome! I also recommend #node.js on irc.freenode.net for short questions. Very helpful people there.